# Uninstalling intel HAXM on Mac (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, intel, haxm

I ran into an error after installing VMware Fusion on my mac, that it couldn't find /dev/vmmon.  After some digging, I've learned that there are only so many available character devices, and that other software I have has consumed them.

Since I actively use Viscosity and Virtualbox (for the time being), the only other one that I could find I had was Intel HAXM driver.

Instructions online suggest to run a script to uninstall it, however that script did not exist on my laptop.

I unloaded the driver with the command:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

I wanted to determine if there is anything else I need to do, will this driver attempt to reload during boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue, Tim Potter's solution fixed my issue ,

```
sudo kextunload -b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

The [Intel HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS#Removing_Intel_HAXM) docs show that as of 2018, there is an uninstall script:
`sudo /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find /dev/vmmon (VMware Fusion 8.5.1 on macOS 10.12.1)

I had the same problem.
After a lot of trial and error, and helpful support from VMware I got it to work by

1. Create another user on the mac
2. log in as that new user
3. start fusion
4. create a new virtual machine (custom, windows7, no actual OS installation)
5. If machine starts, then vmmon is restored correctly
6. switch back to your normal user, start fusion and your existing vm

I have not investigated WHY this works, and VMware-support couldn´t tell me either. For now - I do not care. It works, and I can run my vms again.